QGIS - transfer outcrop pixels from a DEM raster onto another raster surface at a lower level
In QGIS I would like a solution that will transfer pixels from a DEM raster onto another raster surface at a lower level. I am trying to create 2 geological surfaces, one being ground level (GL) and the other subsurface. On the GL surface (a DEM layer) are a number of hillocks that are outcrops from the subsurface layer (DEM layer). I have a vector layer that defines the extents of the hillocks as polygons. I would like to be able to transfer the hillock pixels from the GL layer by extending the slopes down to merge with the subsurface layer (as in the attached diagram). Is there a solution for this please?


I have not tested this method, it's merely a theoretical but it should work. The efficacy would depend a bit on how regular your geological surface is and how steep the sides of the outcrops are.

Clip your surface DTM using your outcrop polygons

Buffer your outcrop polygons by an amount which is enough to cover the slope between the geological surface and the outcrop - you'll need to experiment with this and it'll depend on how steep the outcrop sides are.

Use these buffered polygons to erase these areas of the geological surface so you get a raster with holes in (various methods you could do this)

Mosaic the clipped surface raster together with the erased geology raster - you'll get a raster with doughnut holes of no data around your outcrops

Use GRASS r.fillnulls to fill these no data areas using interpolation from either side of the no data - this should fill in the doughnut holes and give you a continuous raster surface


